# Proper initialization of a Blazor instance created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am working in Blazor WASM. I had some questions about creating new tabs/windows in Blazor and the state of the new tab.

I create a new tab/window via a JSInterop call:

```
window.open('\anotherpage', windowName);
```

I expect the new window is a new instance of the Blazor WASM sandboxed from the original. I notice that the new instance does not seem to be initialized properly. For instance, if I attempt to access a service  that works in the original:

```
[Inject]
public SomeService someService { get; set; } //Singleton service started in program.cs
```

In the original this works obviously, but in the new one I get a null exception accessing SomeService.

Does this mean the new instance is not initialized as it normally would?  Am I misunderstanding what is happening here? Is there a way to initialize the services properly, or do I just have to construct anything I need?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a typo error:  [Inject]
public SomeService {get;set;}

Comment: I'm honestly surprised it does anything other than opening a new and _blank_ window/tab.  From the docs, "If the empty string ("") is specified as url, a blank page is opened into the targeted browsing context."

Answer (score -1):

It appears that all services in program are available and initialized the same in all duplicate instances of the WASM. I just had an initialization bug on that particular page.